# Sorting Crosstab didn't work for more than 2 sort keys in BIRT

Tags: sorting, birt, crosstab

I am a new BIRT user. After a few research and testing, I am able to sort crosstab by column's value by using sorting tab in crosstab properties and fill in the **select row member value** with value to sort. But then I found out that I can't make it work for more than 2 sort keys.

For instance, I was setting 4 column's value as the sort key. The first 2 is working just fine, but not #3 and #4. To make sure, i am deleting the first sort key, then #2 and #3 is working but not #4, and so on.

Do anyone know how to work around on this problem?

BTW I have post a bug report for this, even when I am not really sure whether it is a bug or not. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425510

Comment: Still no answer. :( I really hope that BIRT developer could read and answer my problem here or on the bug report link above. At least someone could show me the alternative way for the solution.